# Tax liability of living in a property that is owned by the company you work for

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, liability

If the CEO of company A lives not-permenantly (1yr) in a property that is currently owned (mortgaged) by company A which they are an employee of, will there be a tax liability implied for said CEO ?

How can I find out more about a situation like this? Both from a state and federal perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to posit that the housing is provided as a benefit and the employee is not charged rent. The value of the housing is likely [taxable to the employee](https://www.mossadams.com/articles/2014/october/employer-provided-housing):

> Unless an exception applies, the full value of the housing is treated as additional taxable compensation to the employee. Full or partial exceptions apply if the housing is:
>
> - Provided for the convenience of the employer
> - A temporary work location
> - Lodging furnished by an educational institution

Comment: I wonder if there is an additional complication because it is the CEO. Somebody in that position may have a significant ownership stake, and would that change the nature of the benefit from salary to something else.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I think providing a company asset for *personal* use counts as compensation regardless of ownership stake. Even if the CEO owns part of the company, the CEO doesn't personally own the company's property.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of this answer I am going to ignore the CEO part.

It is very unlikely that the benefit will be tax free.

[IRS pub 15-b](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p15b#en_US_2020_publink1000193699)describes what needs to be done to have the fringe benefit not be taxable for the employee: The document is from the view of the employer.

> **Lodging on Your Business Premises**
>
> You can exclude the value of lodging you furnish to an employee from
> the employee's wages if it meets the following tests.
>
> - It is furnished on your business premises.
> - It is furnished for your convenience.
> - The employee must accept it as a condition of employment.
>
> Different tests may apply to lodging furnished by educational
> institutions. See section 119(d) of the Internal Revenue Code for
> details.
>
> If you allow your employee to choose to receive additional pay instead
> of lodging, then the lodging, if chosen, isn’t excluded. The exclusion
> also doesn't apply to cash allowances for lodging.

The document also gives examples.

Then it has one more caveat:

> **S corporation shareholders.**
>
> For this exclusion, don't treat a 2% shareholder of an S corporation
> as an employee of the corporation. A 2% shareholder is someone who
> directly or indirectly owns (at any time during the year) more than 2%
> of the corporation's stock or stock with more than 2% of the voting
> power. Treat a 2% shareholder as you would a partner in a partnership
> for fringe benefit purposes, but don't treat the benefit as a
> reduction in distributions to the 2% shareholder. For more
> information, see Revenue Ruling 91-26, 1991-1 C.B. 184.

Is the CEO a 2% shareholder? Is the corporation a S corp?

More digging would be needed to understand this additional wrinkle..

Comment: Good points! This is a small business S corp - the "CEO" is more like a sales director and has 0 ownership (for now). There is one founder who has 100% of the equity and manages the day-to-day